# How to set or retain original object size in photogrammetry scans with apps such as Kiri Engine?

Tags: cad, scanning, artificial-intelligence, photogrammetry, nerf

I noticed when scanning objects using photogrammetry or the AI-based Neural Radiance Field (NeRF) in apps such as Kiri Engine that the original size is not retained in the object.

How can I actually retain the original size, or set the proper sizes when or after scanning objects like that? So that, when 3D printed it is the same size as the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reference objects

When scanning something, including a simple reference geometry, such as a cube, is best. This can then be used to scale the final model to the correct size and as a reference for if the item has the correct angles. Besides cubes, coins (esp. matte ones) make handy markers and scale references.

If your scan contains color values, a simple photo scale angle could suffice. That item would be taken directly from photography. There it is sometimes required to contain size information and a pointer to the angle the photo was made at. This is made by using a square or angle with scale markings and distortions of the item can be solved later till the angle appears properly and to the right scale.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do this automatically? Like select the object and tell the size. I can think of 3D scanning something first. Then make a photo of the object with a reference, use overlay to position but it likely won't be too accurate. What if you want milimeter precision? It's hard to do manually with a reference object.

Comment: @BobOrtiz I don'T think Kiri has it, but some scan engines with turntable from about 2020 used a reference item they scanned first before scanning an actual item on the turntable, using the known reference as scale

Comment: I have a RevoPoint Inspire with a turntable and 'magic pad' too, I suppose they use those markers as reference too. But so far I absolutely hate using it.